# Is this Artificial Intelligence [Logo] a virus?

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, malware, malware-detection, virus-scanning

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uZQE0.jpg]

I was having trouble with my WiFi driver so I ran one command SFC/scannow. It showed it has found some errors and fixed those after that I'm having this AI problem. I found nothing on the internet. Does anyone know about it? Thanks for your help.

Comment: How is this programming related?

Comment: I don't know! It could be!

Comment: @AnuragBhagsain: No, it could not.

Answer (score 0):

According to me , an Artificial Intelligence has :

1. Large number of data that is it requires high storage.
2. It is implemented in sophisticated enviroments or softwares
3. Implemented in softwares where prediction of events is required.

I conclude that your problem **is not an Artificial Intelligence.**